# Can’t get aws lambda/DynamoDB api to work

Tags: api, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, crud-repository

It is my first time trying the Aws dynamoDB and Lambda node.js. I followed exact instructions on the aws documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-dynamo-db.html#http-api-dynamo-db-attach-integrations

Here’s the function code I used, as gotten from step 10 of the documentation

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };

  try {
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "DELETE /items/{id}":
        await dynamo
          .delete({
            TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Deleted item ${event.pathParameters.id}`;
        break;
      case "GET /items/{id}":
        body = await dynamo
          .get({
            TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        break;
      case "GET /items":
        body = await dynamo.scan({ TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items" }).promise();
        break;
      case "PUT /items":
        let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        await dynamo
          .put({
            TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items",
            Item: {
              id: requestJSON.id,
              price: requestJSON.price,
              name: requestJSON.name
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Put item ${requestJSON.id}`;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

But each time I try the API’s as it is structured on the documentation, I get ‘internal server error’. I have tried it on both terminal, and from postman, same error. I couldn’t get any helpful links elsewhere to solve this. Is there something I need to do different?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons a Lambda would return a 500 exception to APIGW, for example:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-stage-variable-500/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-internal-server-error/

My suggestion is to strip back your function code, and only return a response to APIGW with no other logic and test that. Then you can decide to work forwards or backwards from there.